# Creating an sqlite3 table with c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I know their is another question with this exact title but it doesn't solve my problem, so here goes.

I am following a tutorial on using SQLite with c++, but when I run my program to create the database table, I get an error;

```cpp
static int create_database(const char *s);
static int create_table(const char *s);

int main(){
    const char *file = "Mafia.sqlite";
    sqlite3 *db;

    create_database(file);
    create_table(file);
}

static int create_database(const char* s){
    sqlite3 *db = NULL;
    int query = 0;

    query = sqlite3_open_v2(s, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    cout << "Database created successfully!\n";
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}

static int create_table(const char* s){
    sqlite3 *db;

    string sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS("
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                "USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL,"
                "PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL);";

    try{
       int query = 0;
       query = sqlite3_open_v2(s, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);

       char *error_message;
       query = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &error_message);

       if(query != SQLITE_OK){
           cerr << "Error occurred creating table!\n";
           sqlite3_errmsg(db);
           sqlite3_free(error_message);
       }else
           cout << "Table created successfully\n";
       sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    catch(const exception &e){
        cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }

}
```

My terminal returns the following:

```sh
Database created successfully!
Error occurred creating table!
test(13698,0x109148dc0) malloc: Non-aligned pointer 0x102bd9641 being freed
test(13698,0x109148dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

**Edit**
I corrected the sql error and I still have the same problem

**Thanks.**

Comment: Drop the comma in your SQL statement, the one right before the closing paren.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That explains why creating the table failed, but not the error from malloc afterwards.

Comment: I just corrected the error, and I still have the same error as above

Comment: What value is being returned by `sqlite3_open_v2`? You assign the value to `query` (for both calls) but do not look at it.

Comment: @JaMiT sqlite3_open_v2 returns 14

Comment: The value 14 corresponds to [can't open](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#cantopen). Could you confirm that the error occurs in the call to `sqlite3_exec` (by printing a diagnostic message before and after that call)? It would make sense for that call to fail when given a bogus database connection handle.

Comment: You should open the database once and use that connection in everything, instead of opening it in each function.

Comment: I finally got it to work by changing `sqlite3_open_v2` to `sqlite_open` @JaMiT , thanks

Comment: `sqlite3_errmsg(db);` does... absolutely nothing. You should just print out `error_message` in your error message.

Comment: @Shawn I will give you approach a try, and i forgot to remove `sqlite3_errmsg(db)` from the question, it is not in my working copy.

Comment: @moony If you know why changing the command helped, you should post that as an answer. Also, please try to remember in the future to check for errors after trying to open a resource. It'll save you problems down the road. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things,
First you need to initialize error_message to `nullptr`. Otherwise `sqlite3_free` will cause a crash since error_message is having some garbage value.

Secondly, according to the [SQLITE documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), you need to use atleast one of the three options while opening an SQLITE connection,

1. SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY
2. SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE
3. SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE

You are not supposed to use SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE as a standalone option.

If you change these two, it should work fine.